# Monodroid DrawerLayout

Tags: xamarin.android, drawerlayout

I am not able to use **DrawerLayout** in my project. In my android sdk manager, I have upgraded the "Android SDK platform-tools" to the latest revision (Rev. 22.3) and the "Android SDK Built-tools ( Rev. 19.0.1 ) as suggested in this post

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4440/create-a-drawer-layout

Still I cannot find this component (DrawerLayout). Visual studio suggests to generate this class since it cannot find it in any referenced library. I have referenced Mono.Android.Support.v4.
( I am also using ActionBarSherlock libraries to target api levels <= 2.3).
Any help as to what i am doind wrong, where to investigate or what direction to take will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest upgrading your Xamarin.Android version and your current dlls to the new "Xamarin" versions.

EX:

```
<Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4">
  <HintPath>Components\xamandroidsupportv7appcompat-7.18.0\lib\android\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

You can add these by right-clicking the components folder and searching for support libraries.

Here's v4: https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamandroidsupportv4-18

Comment: Thanks. I have upgraded to a newer version (4.8.1) and it is working now.